# How to modify basic paragraph in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typesetting

After pressing OK button new paragraph rule created. But I need to modify basic paragraph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make a note of the changes you've made and then double-click or Option/Alt-click the `Basic Paragraph` style. You can then redefine the options in the dialog window.

**Photoshop, unlike other Adobe applications, does not currently have a method for updating a paragraph style via selecting an altered piece of text.** Many of the character and paragraph style options in Photoshop are not nearly as advanced as other Adobe applications.

In other Adobe applications, *but not Photoshop*, if you started with `Basic Paragraph` and made changes and then want to update `Basic Paragraph` with the new settings, Right-Click (Windows) or Control-Click (Macintosh) and choose "Redefine Style" from the contextual menu. But again, this functionality does not exist within Photoshop at this time.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something really wrong, your technique does not work. In fact, it was exactly what I tried myself when I was trying to answer the question. No matter how I reach Basic Paragraph, if I make any changes, it creates a new paragraph style. What are @yakunins and I doing wrong? We're not trying to redefine from text. We're trying to alter the default.

Comment: I know you can't make it in PS's GUI, but Basic Paragraph's settings are stored somewhere. Probably, they are in the registry.

Comment: @yakunins Wait, you want to change the default settings? I don't think you can.